# Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Oracle 19.0.48.0.0

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

We just upgraded to Oracle 19c (19.3.0) and all apps stopped working with this error message:

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Oracle 19.0.48.0.0

I updated Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to 19.3.0

Any solution?

Comment: I am not using it. Seems like cache issue. Working on it

Comment: that's Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, better check before comment

Comment: Hard to believe. The error message is quite clear. I would suggest to contact Oracle support. Check with `Connection.GetType().Assembly.Location` to see which DLL is actually loaded.

Comment: Cleaning solution fixed it