# Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support Oracle 19.0.96.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

One of my ASP.NET application was working with oracle 10g without any issue. I have upgraded the database to 19c and changed connection string accordingly. Now projects compiles and when I run I get this error.

[image]

When I debug, I get this error.

[image]

What can be the reason and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Hi @A.M.Roomi . Probably your framework ODP is not compatible with 19c. which version do you currently have of ODP ??

Comment: @RobertoHernandez - Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version 12.2.1100 installed

Comment: that version is supported for Win8*/Win8.1*/2012*/2012R2*/Win7*/2016*/
Win10*/x64** , and for a net framework 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, or 4.6.2, 4.7 . Do you have any of these ?

Comment: Yes I have Windows 8.1, VS 2019 and .Net framework 4.5

Comment: did you try to clean the cache ? see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717088/oracle-data-provider-for-net-does-not-support-oracle-19-0-48-0-0

Comment: Yes I followed the same but no luck

Comment: Are you sure about the driver? Verify with `Debug.WriteLine(conn.GetType().Assembly.FullName);`

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text for code and error messages.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I updated the .Net framework from 4.5 to 4.8.1 and changed all "TargetFramwork" from net45 to net48 and also update Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package to the latest version but also have the same error.....I tried to update Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to 19. x  but also the same error.......when I verify which dll is actually loaded by using "conn.GetType().Assembly.FullName" I get: "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral"

Comment: So, it loads version `Version=4.121.2.0` - which is obviously not version 19. Check your [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). Note, assemblies in GAC take precedence over any DLL's stored in the application directory!

Answer (score 5):

You need to update [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) package to 19.x.

I had the same issue, with the same version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (12.2.1100) and Oracle Database 19.0.128.0.0.
After installing the new version, it took a while for VS2019 **really** update it. Even though the new version was installed, in runtime it was referencing the older version. I had to clean package cache and reinstall. After that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer as my versions appeared slightly different from earlier posted.
I ran into this error

> [ArgumentException: Oracle Data Provider for .NET does not support
> Oracle 19.0.112.0.0]

while running a Visual Studio solution using
*VS2019/Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production* originally written using
VS2017/ODP.NET 12.1.24160719
due to the underlying Oracle upgrade to 19c Edition.

Performed the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Nuget upgrade from v12x to v19x from within the Visual Studio

**Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution**

[image]

which resolved the issue for me.